# How to delete pre-installed Libreoffice from KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, libreoffice, development, beta

I installed Libreoffice 4.2 (yes, beta release, much better) when I was on Ubuntu, but then, I installed KDE desktop and Libreoffice came together with KDE. So now I have 2 libreoffice installed, one is development version (beta) and another one is normal, which came with KDE.

How to uninstall that version which came together with KDE?

---

**Additional info:**

[CLICK ON ME, ITS A LINK TO PICTURE. (I am not allowed to post pictures yet)](http://s26.postimg.org/5u08p3fop/screenshot.png)

Sorry, I was using Windows 7 that moment. But I usually use Kubuntu.

.

.

I opened terminal:

**sudo su**

**apt-get remove libreoffice*.***

**apt-get install /home/myUserName/Downloads/LibreOfficeFolder/DEBS/***

After that I would like to figure out how to remove from kde search that old libre office. I think I need to remove cache somehow, but I didn't find in google how. Searching using mause in categories seems that old libreoffice dissapeared and new appears, but using search I can'f find new one, only old one. (old one is removed!)

*P.S. I edited this comment because of comment of this comment ;)*

Comment: How did you install the beta release? Having that would help us solve your question!

Comment: I've edited my main comment for better explanation. Any suggestions? :)